# Understand help me array in assembly?

Tags: disassembly, assembly

Can anyone explain the following code as it's an array in assembly. 
I can't understand can you help me to figure it out line by line.

Thanks

[image]

Q.1) what does the 401024  & 40102E   line does ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is given in the book immediately following the listing (Practical Malware Analysis Chapter 6 page 128 "Recognizing C Code Constructs in Assembly"):

> In this listing, the base address of array b corresponds to `dword_40A000` ,
>   and the base address of array a corresponds to `var_14` . Since these are both
>   arrays of integers, each element is of size 4, although the instructions at 1
>   and 2 differ for accessing the two arrays. In both cases, `ecx` is used as the
>   index, which is multiplied by 4 to account for the size of the elements. The
>   resulting value is added to the base address of the array to access the proper
>   array element.

Comment: How did you know that was the book in screenshot?

Comment: @Biswapriyo I have the book

Comment: Ah, exact same question than [index of array in assembly?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18710/index-of-array-in-assembly). Possible duplicate...