# index of array in assembly?

Tags: disassembly, assembly

In the following picture the line i want to mention is:

```
mov [esp+eax*4+0Ch], edx
```

Here `eax` is the index in the array. But, where is the address of the array to access?

what does mean this line of code ? (`0Ch`)

[image: Full context of the asm line]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, when running through an array, we can find the following lines of assembly code:

```
mov [base_address_of_array + array_index * size_of_an_item_in_array], edx
```

In your case, my guess would be that the array is on the stack (that is why you find `esp` as part of the base address of the array. Then, you also have an offset to `esp` which is `0Ch` (which is 12 in decimal). So, the array is located at `esp + 0Ch`. Then, `eax` is the index and `4` is the size of an item in the array (probably an integer of 4 bytes).

If we look at the whole CFG, I would translate it back to C in something like this:

```
int array[4];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  array[i] = i;
```

**Note**: I supposed that the blue arc in the CFG is getting back to `loc_401381`.

Comment: The assembly code looks like pointer arithmetic with arrays. Isn't it?